# Painting harmonic waves Android

Tags: android

I am making an app that looks like the pic below, the bottom harmonic wave doesn't change but the top one will by setting the amplitude, omega, omega inverse and phi.

[image]

I have x and y lines but I cant seem figure out how to even paint the bottom wave, y = sin(x). I have searched and tried to do it but have failed. Can anyone help or give direction to a resource that will help?

Comment: How did you paint the top one? Should be the same, but with a y offset.

Comment: I didn't paint either waves, that's what I am trying to do

Comment: Look at the sensors/accelerometer thing in legacy sdk samples to get an idea.

Comment: Nothing moves. I am trying to draw a basic harmonic wave

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example drawing two sine waves, taking care of view size changes, some axis scaling and  simulation stepping.

---

```xml
<com.pixdart.view.HarmonicCustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DDD"/>
```

```java
public class HarmonicCustomView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private RectF mRectF = new RectF();
    private float scaleY, scaleX;
    public static final float STEP_X = 0.1f;
    public static final int PERIODS_TO_SHOW = 5;

    public HarmonicCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public HarmonicCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public HarmonicCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mRectF.set(0, 0, w, h);
        mRectF.inset(mRectF.width() * 0.1f, mRectF.height() * 0.1f);
        scaleX = (float) (2 * Math.PI * PERIODS_TO_SHOW / mRectF.width());
        scaleY = mRectF.height() / 6;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        for (float x = 0; x < mRectF.width(); x += STEP_X) {
            float y = (float) (Math.sin(x * scaleX)) * scaleY;
            canvas.drawPoint(x + mRectF.left, y + mRectF.top + scaleY, mPaint);
        }

        mPaint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
        for (float x = 0; x < mRectF.width(); x += STEP_X) {
            float y = (float) (Math.sin(x * scaleX)) * scaleY;
            canvas.drawPoint(x + mRectF.left, y + mRectF.top + scaleY * 5, mPaint);
        }
    }
}
```